# What does angle brackets do on class names in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I know how you can use `List<T>` for example and decide what that collection is holding. That's where T comes in. But I'm not sure I understand the brackets fully.

If I create a class...

```
class MyClass<int> { }
```

Or instead of int I could use T or object or string or whatever. What does that mean? Does it turn into a collection automatically?

Comment: This is a Generic Class, nothing to do with collections. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/sz6zd40f.aspx) and come back if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 6):

**Generic classes allow class members to use type parameters.** They are defined in the same way as generic methods, by adding a type parameter after the class name.

```
class Point<T>
{
  public T x, y;
}
```

To instantiate an object from the generic class the standard notation is used, but with the type argument specified after both class names. Note that in contrast to generic methods, a generic class must always be instantiated with the type argument explicitly specified.

```
Point<short> p = new Point<short>();
```

**Reference:** http://www.pvtuts.com/csharp/csharp-generics

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 1):

T means Type. MyClass is a generic class if you use "MyClass". More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)