# Why this is not possible in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

When I write below code :

```
public interface IDoSomething<in TFrom> 
    {
        void Process(TFrom content, string path);

        void Process<TTemplate>(TFrom content, TTemplate template, string path);

    }

       public class ConcreteWorkA<string> : IDoSomething<string>
    {

        public void Process(string content, string path)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Process<TTemplate>(string content, TTemplate template, string path)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

It does not compile where below line compiles,

```
     public class ConcreteWorkB<String> : IDoSomething<String>
    {

        public void Process(String content, string path)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Process<TTemplate>(String content, TTemplate template, string path)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

I also understand that `public class ConcreteWorkB : IDoSomething<String>` is correct but then below code works.

```
     public class COncreteWorkC<DataTable> : IDoSomething<DataTable>// Datatable from System.Data
    {
        public void Process(DataTable content, string path)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Process<TTemplate>(DataTable content, TTemplate template, string path)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }                 
    }
```

Since string is alias for String I am expecting it to work. Also why the difference in behavior.
I am using VS 2019 , .Net 5.

The error I get is

1. Syntax error, ',' expected
2. Identifier expected

EDit: Comments and Accepted answer explain that String/DataTable is treated as generic type parameter not concrete type, where as string is hence the error.

Comment: What do you expect a line of `DoesSomething<string> : IDoSomething<string>{}` to do? Note that `DoesSomething<String> : IDoSomething<String>{}` doesn't compile either. If you're trying to specify a class declaration, please make that clear. A [mcve] would really, really help your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet: `DoesSomething<String>` actually compiles, seems the compiler treats `String` as just a generic parameter type name. https://dotnetfiddle.net/IzSbUg

Comment: If that's `class DoesSomething<string> : IDoSomething<string> {}` then the first `string` is the placeholder name for your generic type, so it isn't allowed because it's getting it confused with the [built-in type `string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types). I'm not 100% sure if you think you're specifying that the type should be `string`, or if you're aware that's the _name_ for your generic type parameter.

Comment: OP: You need to explain your _expected behaviour_ here. Note again that `DataTable` isn't referencing `System.Data.DataTable`, but naming the generic parameter `DataTable` (so I could create an instance of `DoesSomething` like `new DoesSomething<int>()` or `new DoesSomething<MyClass>();`).

Comment: I'm wondering if your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822301/what-does-angle-brackets-do-on-class-names-in-c).

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822301/what-does-angle-brackets-do-on-class-names-in-c). You've misunderstood what `class ConcreteWorkA<string> : IDoSomething<string>` and `class COncreteWorkC<DataTable>` are declaring.

Comment: @Llama: Thanks, Yes datatable is treated as generic parameter not the type... Stupid of me... was just looking at using at the top...

Comment: Of course. Putting `<something>` after the class name makes it a generic class, with `something` as the type placeholder. If you don't want to make the class generic, don't make it generic.

Comment: This really should not be closed, in my opinion. It's an interesting edge case where an existing type name is used as a generic parameter name and somehow compiler allows that. This could be confusing to newbies and deserves a proper explanation.

Comment: @JonSkeet: added the example, did not add in first attempt to avoid information overload...

Comment: @WiktorZychla: `DoesSomething<String>` doesn't compile *on its own*. It compiles as the type of a variable declaration for example, but weren't given that context. See the initial version of the question.

Comment: @anshu: Providing a minimal complete example is far from information overload. It doesn't take much to make it clear that you're trying to write a class declaration. Your edit is *still* incomplete as now you haven't declared `IDoSomething<T>` anywhere. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: @JonSkeet: what I have seen (and I don't know if it was the original version) was `interface IDoSomething<in TSource> : IDisposable { } class DoesSomething<String> : IDoSomething<String>`. This was enough to reason about why `String` works there and `string` doesn't.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: The original version didn't have `class` in there. See the edit history. It was *just* `DoesSomething<string> : IDoSomething<string>{}` which is invalid whether the `s` is capitalized or not.

Comment: @JonSkeet: correct, I confirm. Somehow I missed this typo and focused on actual issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an interesting case on what is allowed as a generic parameter type name.
This:

```
class DoesSomething<T> : IDoSomething<string>
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

and this

```
class DoesSomething<T> : IDoSomething<String>
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

is obvious. Here `T` is used as a generic parameter name.

On the other hand this

```
class DoesSomething<string> : IDoSomething<string>
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

doesn't make much sense, since it tries to introduce a concrete type (`string`) as a parameter name where only fresh names are allowed.

What is only interesting here is that it actually works where a generic parameter type name **collides** with an existing type name. Looks like the compiler allows that but of course gives different meaning to both `String`s.

```
public interface IDoSomething<in TSource> : IDisposable { }

class DoesSomething<String> : IDoSomething<String>
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DoesSomething<int> _ = new DoesSomething<int>();
    }
}
```

The `String` in `IDoSomething<String>` is bound to `TSource` in the interface definition.

The `String` in `DoesSomething<String>` introduces a type parameter which is then expected to be provided by the client (`int` in the example above).

Comment: I think the difference is that `string` is a [built-in type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types) in the C# language (even though it's just an alias), whereas `String` is a class provided by .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the nice and detailed explanation, it was the problem due to String being treated as generic type parameter not concrete type. Although the type param in code did not make sense but needed to understand.

Comment: @Llama: actually `string` is a type alias. `System.String` is a builtin .NET type. Just `String` could then refer to `System.String` assuming you have `using System` above or a typename, like `T`. That's why this case seems quite interesting.

Comment: @Wiktor I think you're perhaps missing my point. Yes, it's an alias (as I said), but that alias type is native to the C# language (yes language, not .NET - I know the lines are a bit blurred here). `String` is the aliased type, but that belongs to .NET, and is namespaced. The point is that you can remove all `using` declarations but still use `string` because it's part of the language, but you need `using System` to use `String` (or you can reference it as `System.String`) because it isn't part of the language.

Comment: Even declaring a class outside of a namespace doesn't stop its name being usable as a generic type, so it must be that it's a built-in type for the C# language.

Comment: @Llama: yes, seems so. However, this might be confusing. One would easily spot the cause if it was anything other than `String` (like a custom `Foo`). However, the edge case of `String` being treated differently when used on `DoesSomething<String> : IDoSomething<String>` is worth of pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your actual code? If so then you need a class I expect, it might also be worth adding the 'in' keyword to the type for it:

```
public interface IDoSomething<in TSource> : IDisposable{}
public class DoesSomething<in string> : IDoSomething<string>
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```