# TUser in PasswordHasher<TUser> password = new();

Tags: c#, .net

I have seen the following example code online which would allow me to make use of the `PasswordHasher` class.

```cs
PasswordHasher<TUser> password = new();
```

However, I do not quite understand what `<TUser>` means syntax wise and also what should be passed as `TUser` when using it.

If I replace `TUser` with `string` I can make it work, as shown below:

```cs
PasswordHasher<string> password = new();
string password_encrypted = password.HashPassword("Carl", "Fruit");
```

So I would like to know two things. What does the first line mean if described in English (I'm not sure what `PasswordHasher<TUser>` means)
and secondly, if I want to to `TUser` instead of `string`, how would I achieve this?

Comment: `new PasswordHasher<TUser>` means exactly the same as `new PasswordHasher<string>`, just with `TUser` instead of `string`, and `TUser` is the name of a specific class, just like `string`, to use which you need to have it (`class TUser {}`), which you probably don't, otherwise it would have worked just like with `string`. Now, `class PasswordHasher<TUser>` means [something different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25822301/11683).

Comment: @GSerg: "to use which you need to have it (`class TUser {}`)" - well, it *might* also be there as a generic parameter of the enclosing method or type. (And the naming makes me think that's what it is supposed to be.)

Answer (score 0):

The example I believe you are referencing is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordhasher-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0);

So what `TUser` here in this case would be what's called a "generic". Specifically in this case (above), `TUser` must be a "class".

You can read up on generics [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics).

Generics are a way of performing generic actions against a particular object.